# How to get a specific data from dataflow to be used in other activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have my Data Flow designed with Dataflow activity in it. The Dataflow gives my sink data as something like this

```
{"BaseObject":"ABCD","OHY":"AAS"}
{"BaseObject":"DEFG","OHY":"LOI"}
{"BaseObject":"POIU","OHY":"JJI"}
```

Now I need each value of BaseObject and have to pass it as a parameter to a web activity one by one so it will be like for each loop where one value of BaseObject is taken at a time and then passed to the web activity as a parameter, which is in turns gives me my final JSON.

[image]

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `dataflow` activty is executed, data will be loaded to the sink dataset. To get the sink results of dataflow activity, use another activity (lookup) and connect it to the sink dataset.

1. In the pipeline, connect the `lookup` activity after the `dataflow` activity and read the **sink** dataset to get the data loaded.

Dataflow:

Sink dataset:

[image]

sink settings:

[image]

pipeline:

[image]

**Output of lookup activity:**

[image]

2. Connect the lookup output to the `Foreach` activity, to loop the value **BaseObject**.

`@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

[image]

3. You can use this current item (**@item().BaseObject**) of activities inside the Foreach activity.

**Ex:**

[image]

Comment: I dont see any dataset property for the lookup activity . i have added the screen shot now

Comment: Is your dataflow sink dataset same as in lookup activity? Can you share your dataflow sink dataset details?

Comment: yes its same dataset

Comment: Can you share your dataflow sink dataset details?

Comment: added sink dataset screen shot now

Comment: thank you, but this is sink transformation Snip. Can you open the Json1 dataset from this sink and give that details?

Comment: ok, added now .

Comment: As the sink file name is not parameterized and when you use the same dataset in lookup it is not finding the file and gives an error. You can follow any one of these 2 options. 1) Create a new dataset for lookup and select the file which is generated by the sink. 2) You can parameterize the dataset file name in sink transformation and provide details from the pipeline as mentioned in my snips and use the same dataset for lookup activity. Updated my answer with new snips.

Comment: I am not sure I get it, What do you mean, sink file name is not parameterized? Should I create a parameter and pass that in Dataflow as sink file name? and later use that parameter in lookup?

Comment: I still will not see Dataset properties. How do you see dataset property section in Lookup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240309/discussion-between-niharikamoola-mt-and-zzzsharepoint).